# SSL issue. NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

Previously I used RapidSSL certificate. After it expired I moved to Lets Encrypt (free ssl) and installed on my server. But site uses still old SQL certificate after couple of refreshes taking new SSL certificate and resources (css, images, scripts) are not loading gives NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error.

I restarted Apache couple of times.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: "But site uses still old ssl certificated after couple of refreshes" That means your configuration is incorrect, you need to review it and provide it in your question if you want help. But not here since it is not related to programming. Have a look at [su] or [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID means your SSL certificate date is invalid, that is because your old certificate has expired. Check your apache config to make sure that - certificate files mentioned are the desired ones. For detail debugging of your problem, you need to look at your apache server log could be located at /var/log/apache2.

Comment: I checked expiry date of ssl it : oct 12th 2019. but giving NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error for few resources.